# Matlab: definite integral of numerical vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, numerical-integration

i'm looking for to solve a definite integral of two vectors, I try to explain.

I know: z vector of numbers and G(z) vector of numbers.

The limits of integration are zmin and zmax

I should to calculate: 
Integral between zmin,zmax of [G(z) * z^(7/6)] dz

Could I solve with the following code?

```
For i = zmin:zmax
myresult = G(z(i))*z(i)^(7/6)
end
```

Comment: Is the code you are showing intended to be Matlab syntax or pseudo-code?

Comment: the integral is pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

(wrote before)

> You can use [numerical integral](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html).
>
> Define G(z) as a function handle, and the function to be integrated as
>   another one. You can find an example in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24763578/3839249).

---

So your goal is to calculate the sum of `[G(z) * z^(7/6)] * dz`, where `G(z)` and `z` are pre-calculated numerical vectors, `dz` a small increment value.

```
dz = (zmax - zmin) / length(G(z));
S = G * z' * dz;
```

`S` should be the result. Let me explain.

- First of all, I messed up with `G(z)` previously (apologize for that). You have already evaluated (partially) the function to integrate, namely `G(z)` and `z`.
- `G(z)` and `z` are number arrays. Arrays are indexed by integer, starting from 1. So `G(z(i))` may not be a valid expression, as `z(i)` haven't been guaranteed to be integers. The code above only works correctly if you have defined `G(z)` in this way - `G(i) = some_function (z(i));`. By so each element of the same index in two arrays have a meaningful relation.
- There are several ways to evaluate the product of two arrays (vectors), generating a single-value sum. A `for` loop works, but is inefficient. `G * z'` is the way to calc [vector dot product](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html).

Comment: Thank Yvon, but I did not understand how to define G(z). I tried the following code:  fun = @(z) g(z).*z.^(7/6);
q = integral(fun,z(1),z(end-1)); but I receive "Undefined function 'g' for input arguments of type 'double'"

Comment: 2 things to note - Do you have a clear definition of G(z)? Post here so maybe I can help you build a function handle. Also, you don't need z(1) and z(end-1) in `integral`, they are just two numbers, not a complicated function (or are they?)

Comment: G(z) is a vector of double as Z and they have the same length

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that. This then leads to a different answer.

Comment: @Mixo Is it possible to show the entire problem? It seems you are defining `z` as integers in the problem, but usually an integral does not pick up integers only.